# sessionStorage - set Item to null

Tags: javascript

I check if a sessionStorage Variable is null, and if true initialize it with "BAR". Otherwhise there should appear a console message with the value of the variable.

```js
sessionStorage.setItem("Foo", null); //I know this would make no sense at this part, this is just here for demo.

if (sessionStorage.getItem("Foo") == null) {
  sessionStorage.setItem("Foo", "BAR");
} else {
  console.log("Foo != null (proof = '", sessionStorage.getItem("Foo"), "')");
}
```

However, It always goes to the else statement and i get the console message which is telling me that the variable is "null", but if it is really "null" then why it is not initialized with "BAR"?

Comment: Is it telling you that it is `"null"` or `null`?

Comment: I guess `null`, there are no `"`

Comment: You can't tell by the code you have there. What does `typeof sessionStorage.getItem("Foo")` say?

Comment: `typeof(sessionStorage.getItem("Foo"))` returns `string`

Comment: It looks like you've stored the string `"null"` in there at some point then, rather than it being an actual `null` value.  They're not the same thing

Comment: Maybe it's setted, but not with a value. Check if it's filled typing in console `sessionStorage` and you'll obtain all your keys. You should find a `Foo` key

Comment: And if you make `sessionStorage.clear()`, after that your code should work

Comment: @JamesThorpe, you are correct. I used `sessionStorage.setItem("Foo", null);` at some point in my script, but why is this considered as a string?

Comment: I think this should be closed as typographycal error, at the end the code works, but it's causing conflicts another piece of code, or older settings.

Comment: @EdwardBlack you can't make that. You can't store objects in sessionStorage. You can only store strings. So to remove something you need `sessionStorage.removeItem("Foo")`

Comment: Because [`setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) requires a string value, anything that isn't will be coerced to a string.  `null` becomes `"null"`.

Comment: Im so sorry, i should know this. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You should be using a strict equality check. `===` instead of `==`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Per your edit, [`setItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) requires the value passed in to be a string (a `DOMString` to be precise), anything else will be coerced to a string.

In your case, you pass in `null`, which is coerced to `"null"`.  When you call `getItem`, you get a string back, which isn't `null`, so your code falls into the `else` block.

If you actually want to clear out an item from storage, the correct method to use is [`removeItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem):

```
sessionStorage.removeItem("Foo");
```

Calling `getItem` now would result in a return value of `null`, not `"null"`.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 storage: sessionStorage or localStorage accepts a string. If a string value is not passed it will convert it to string and save. Hence we should convert the  value to string using (JSON.stringify(value)) and after fetching we should again convert it to the original value.

```
var val = null;
//save to storage
sessionStorage.setItem('a',JSON.stringify(val));

//fetch from storage
var stringValue = sessionStorage.getItem('a');  //outputs "null"
var originalValue = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('a')); //outputs null
```